# How to generate each possible combination of members from two lists (in Python)

Tags: list, loops

I am a Python newbie and I've been trying to find the way to generate each possible combination of members from two lists:

left = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
right = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

The resulting list should be something like:

af ag ah ai aj bf bg bh bi bj cf cg ch ci cj etc...

I made several experiments with loops but I can't get it right: 
The zip function but it wasn't useful since it just pairs 1 to 1 members: 
for x in zip(left,right):
    print x
and looping one list for the other just returns the members of one list repeated as many times as the number of members of the second list :(

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're on the right path, post your loops you've tried and I'll try and point you in the right directly without giving you the answer.

Comment: Well, I experimented with the zip function but it wasn't useful since it just pairs 1 to 1 members.

Comment: Nevermind. Why teach someone to fish when you can just hand them a fish?

Comment: Well, I am just asking for a tiny fish to use it as a bait so I can fish a bigger one :)

Comment: Don't worry @Sinserif, that wasn't directed at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example list comprehension:

```
left = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
right = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
result = [lc + rc for lc in left for rc in right]
print result
```

The result will look like:

```
['af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'bf', 'bg', 'bh', 'bi', 'bj', 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'cj', 'df', 'dg', 'dh', 'di', 'dj', 'ef', 'eg', 'eh', 'ei', 'ej']
```

Comment: COOL! Now I learned about "List Comprehension" and I could assemble the same operations using loops:

left = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
right = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

for A in left:
    for B in right:
        X = A + B
        print X

Comment: To GarySchreiner and PDani: Thanks!. Just one thing: I wasn't lazy, it's just that I don't know enough about Python and sometimes I lack the information necessary to complete something I want to do. @GarySchreiner: A piece of code can teach you a lot if you try to understand it.